# What's the best approach to solve the c# unboxing exception when casting an object to a valuetype?

Tags: c#, unboxing

I just converted a code snippet from VB.NET to C# and stumbled over this issue.

Consider this code:

```
    Dim x As Integer = 5
    Dim y As Object = x
    Dim z As Decimal = CType(y, Decimal)
```

No error from compiler or at runtime. z is five.

Now let's translate this code to C#

```
    int x = 5;
    object y = x;
    decimal z = (decimal)y;
```

No error from compiler but at runtime an exception is thrown:

```
    Cannot unbox "y" to "decimal"
```

Now my question is, which would be the smartest C# way to do this.

Currently my code looks like.

```
    int x = 5;
    object y = x;
    decimal z = decimal.Parse(y.ToString());
```

But another solution would be:

```
    decimal z = (decimal)(int)y;
```

Which looks a bit confusing, but propably has less overhead than decimal.Parse, I guess.

Comment: Is there a reason you are creating the new object y and not letting .net just box x for you?

Comment: For more detailed understanding of the problem and why it behaves this way, you can read http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Comment: @Kevin: This code is just an example. My read code is a function that has an object as a parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(decimal)(int)x` is the right way of doing so if you expect the boxed object to be an integer. Converting to string and parsing is not a good way to attack the problem and incurs some overhead.

If you just know the object can be converted to `decimal` in some way, try `System.Convert.ToDecimal` method. It'll handle that for you.

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
z = Convert.ToDecimal(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert.ToDecimal(y);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be totally safe you could try:

```
    int x = 5;
    object y = x;
    decimal z;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(y.ToString(), out z))
    {
        // z is a decimal
    }
    else
    {
        // z is not a decimal
    }
```

That way if someone sets y to = "donkey" you can handle it without throwing an exception. Of course, you may prefer to throw an exception if z cannot be converted. Just another option...

Comment: That's not necessary, I know that my object is numeric. CType in vb would throw an exception, too, if it's not the case.